# Why Mathematica solves that equation with the solution in complex numbers?

Tags: differential-equations

In order to solve the following Euler Differential Equation I write in the notebook:

```
Assuming[{y∈\[DoubleStruckCapitalR], n>0,x>0},DSolve[x^2 y''[x]+x  y'[x]- n y[x]==0,y[x],x]]
```

And I get as an output:

> {{y[x]->Subscript[[ConstantC], 1] Cosh[Sqrt[n] Log[x]]+I Subscript[[ConstantC], 2] Sinh[Sqrt[n] Log[x]]}}

On the other hand when Mathematica solves the above equation with a specific value for n, for example $n=4$ , it returns the desired solution...

How can I fix this problem, please?

Comment: First, you may see that `\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]` is colored with blue, which means that this has no built-in meaning and doesn't represent the set of real numbers. You should use `Reals` or type with `Esc``reals``Esc`.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min,Thanks but if I write Reals, it does not work either....

Comment: You could specify initial conditions `y[1] == y1` and `y'[1] == yP1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `DSolve` does not really take assumptions. (What I mean, DSolve *seems* to ignore assumptions)

Euler ODE can have 3 different solutions depending on roots $r_1,r_2$ of the characteristic equation. For one repeated root, solution is $y=c_1 x^r+ c_2 x^r \ln x$, and for 2 real and distinct roots, solution is $y=c_1 x^{r_1}+ c_2 x^{r_2}$ and for two complex conjugate roots, solution is $y=c_1 x^{\alpha+i\beta} + c_2 x^{\alpha-i\beta}$

For your case, the roots are $r_1 = -\sqrt{n},r_2 = \sqrt{n}$. Hence for $n>0$ then we are in the second case (2 real distinct roots).

The characteristic equation for Euler ode is found by substituting $y=A x^r$ into the ode and then solving for $r$

You can obtain, for `n>0` the solution you want this way

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ode = x^2 y''[x] + x y'[x] - n y[x] == 0
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image]

```
sol = TrigToExp[sol]
```

[image]

```
sol = Collect[sol, { x^-Sqrt[n], x^Sqrt[n]}]
```

[image]

We are free to rename constants as we want. Hence

```
sol = sol /. {C[1]/2 - (I C[2])/2 -> C[3],    C[1]/2 + (I C[2])/2 -> C[4]}
```

[image]

Verify

```
 ode /. y -> Function[{x}, x^-Sqrt[n] C[3] + x^Sqrt[n] C[4]] // Simplify

 (* True *)
```

**Update**

> what is the characteristic equation?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ode = x^2 y''[x] + x y'[x] - n y[x] == 0;
charEquation = ode /. y -> Function[{x}, A*x^r]
```

[image]

Since $A$ and $x^r$ are non zero, we can divide by them and the above simplifies to

```
Solve[-  n  +  r + (-1 + r) r == 0, r]
```

which gives the solutions

[image]

And since $n>0$ then we have two real distinct roots.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by saying that `DSolve` does not *really* takes assumptions? `DSolve` has an option `Assumptions`.

Comment: @Natas I mean, from experience, I found that assumptions most of the time are ignored by DSolve. Just because you pass assumptions to it, does not mean it will use them.

Comment: OK, I agree. Assumptions cause many problems and are poorly implemented.

Comment: Here we have no constant coefficients, so what is the characteristic equation?

Comment: @dmtri i've updated the answer with the char equation.