# Finding "missing" solutions of differential equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I was working with NDSolve, and suddenly this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225150/why-is-dsolve-returning-imaginary-results), appeared, so I decide to  try something:

Define a differential equation:

```
sole = DSolve[{D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == (n[x])^(1/2), n[1] == 1}, n, x]
```

Plot the results

```
Plot[Evaluate[n[x] /. sole], {x, 0.4, 1}]
```

[image]

Now I tried to solve the same differential equation numerically

```
  sol = NDSolve[{D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == (n[x])^(1/2), n[1] == 1}, n, {x, 0.4, 1}]
```

Plot the results

```
  Plot[n[x] /. sol, {x, 0.4, 1}]
```

[image]

Now mathematica gives only one plot

**Question**

What happened to the other solution?

Comment: `DSolve` appears to be spitting out an unacceptable solution. I believe the blue curve satisfies the differential equation `D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == -(n[x])^(1/2)`, whereas the orange curve satisfies the differential equation `D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == (n[x])^(1/2)`.

Comment: I think that you are right. However I don't understand why mathematica put a minus sign in this equation ```D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == -(n[x])^(1/2)```

Comment: *Mathmatica* does some symbolic pre-processing of differential equations, and perhaps there was a mistake in that, or perhaps it doesn't like it when ODE's that don't satisfy the uniqueness theorem show up.  I don't know. Note that `DSolve[D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == (n[x])^(1/2), n[x], x]` yields only one solution.  Something about that initial condition is making Mathematica choke.

Comment: I didn't take in account the uniqueness theorem, so my next question will be really basic: If I take in account the uniqueness theorem, then the differential equation only has 1 solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplifying on comment by @march

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {D[n[x] (x)^4, x] == (n[x])^(1/2), n[1] == 1};

sole = DSolve[eqns, n, x]

(* {{n -> Function[{x}, (1 + 2 x + x^2)/(4 x^6)]}, {n -> 
   Function[{x}, (1 - 6 x + 9 x^2)/(4 x^6)]}} *)
```

Verify the solutions

```
eqns /. sole // FullSimplify[#, x >= 1/3] &

(* {{False, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

Only the second solution is valid. This is the solution that matches the numeric result.

In general [`extraneous solutions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) are a risk and solutions should be verified.

For numeric results you can check whether the results are "reasonably" close.

```
sol = NDSolve[eqns, n, {x, 2/5, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50][[1]];

Table[(Subtract @@@ eqns) /. sol, {x, 2/5, 1, 1/10}] // N

(* {{-6.2961*10^-29, 0.}, {-2.50343*10^-10, 0.}, {4.90958*10^-9, 
  0.}, {5.45647*10^-9, 0.}, {-3.10546*10^-10, 0.}, {9.492*10^-10, 0.}, {0., 
  0.}} *)
```

Comment: I wonder if this then should be labeled as a bug?

Comment: Suppose that you have a complicated differential equation, that only can be solved numerically, then, how do you know that the numerical result really is the solution of the differential equation?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what do you mean with "reasonably" close. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Cruz - for any equation Abs[LHS-RHS] should evaluate to zero. For a numerical solution there will generally be a non-zero value.  What small value is acceptable will depend on the problem. Whatever threshold is deemed acceptable is what defines reasonably close.